# Connecting cluster to external DB: Fixed node IP Addresses to be whilisted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, proxy, gateway

I have a cluster running in DigitalOcean, and need to connect a RDS hosted Database. What I would normally do is just to whitelist the IP addresses of the machines that would be accessing the database in the AWS Security Groups, and then have clear access to the Database.

The thing is that DigitalOcean Kubernetes nodes get recycled every now and then, and the IP changes. I can manually change the IP to allow connection from every node in my cluster, but this doesn't seem like a very solid solution.

How would I go about fixing the IP of the cluster, or maybe making some sort of gateway with a fixed IP that every outgoing connection from the cluster would go through that? I have been studying but I'm completely ignorant in networking, so anything that could help me point to the right direction would be great.

I've seen there are Forward Proxies (Gateways from what I've read), but I couldn't find much information on that, much of my research ends up in API Gateway (like Kong or something), which I understand is the exact opposite of what I need.

Any help?

Comment: Did you find anything else related to this issue? I'm studying a similar situation and so far, I can only see two options. The first would be to connect to the database through a proxy, where the proxy IP is whitelisted. The second would involve creating and installing a service on every cluster node, that automatically retrieves the node's IP address and updates the whitelist.

Comment: Yeah, so what I found is that is not a very common problem, and probably result of a less then perfect infrastructure design. I ended up moving my database to the same cloud provider, and using a VPC to guarantee access. The two other solutions I've found were exactly the ones you mentioned: (1) using HAProxy or something to route the request or (2) writing a program that keeps updating the IP automatically. The first one seems to be the "best", you control your proxy and don't have the timing risk. The second is a bit sketchy, but could also work I guess.